# Reading and writing integers from/to a binary file in C++

Tags: c++, file-io, binaryfiles, ifstream

The trying to write a simple program that would write integers value into a file, then read and display the integers in the order it was written. The integers written into the file are {0,2,....18}. The following is the code:

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    typedef unsigned int uint32_t;
    // Write to file
    std::ofstream osObj;
    string filename = "testFile";
    osObj.open(filename.c_str(), std::ofstream::binary);

    for (uint32_t i=0; i<10; ++i)
    {
        uint32_t a = i*2;
        osObj.write(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&a), sizeof(a));
        //osObj.write((char *)(&a), sizeof(a));
    }

    //read from file
    std::ifstream isObj;
    isObj.open(filename.c_str(), std::ofstream::binary);
    if (isObj.fail()) { cout<<"Failed to open file"<<endl; }

    for (uint32_t i=0; i<10; ++i)
    {
        char val[sizeof(uint32_t)];
        isObj.read(val, sizeof(val));
        uint32_t* valUint = reinterpret_cast<uint32_t *>(val);
        cout<<*(valUint)<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This doesn't produce the expected result. I'm getting the following output:

```
62586880
62586880
62586880
62586880
62586880
62586880
62586880
62586880
62586880
62586880
```

The byte ordering is little-endian. What am I missing?

Comment: You are missing description of what you expecting and what you are getting

Comment: @Slava edited the question

Comment: Do note that your read loop can look just like your write loop and be  `uint32_t a; osObj.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&a), sizeof(a)); cout << a << endl;`

Comment: @Naveen I see that you edited it, but I do not see desciption what you are getting instead of expecting

Comment: @NathanOliver I tried that (with isObj instead of osObj), but read() complains that arguments are invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't add `i` to `valUint`. You're only reading one integer into `val`, so the integer you just read is at the address pointed to by `valUint`. It's not an array of integers, so there's no reason to index the pointer.

```
    cout<< *valUint << endl;
```

A simpler way to write it is:

```
for (unint32_t i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    uint32_t val;
    isObj.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>&val, sizeof val);
    cout << val << endl;
}
```

Also, you should do `osObj.close()` at the end of the writing loop. The file is buffered, and the buffer may not have been flushed. If you checked for errors when reading, you probably would have noticed that nothing was being read from the file.

Comment: Good catch. But, this does return the right integers as well.

Comment: You also need to close the file between writing and reading it.